# elasticsearch - knn search for an index of 54M records taking too long (more than 100 seconds)

Tags: elasticsearch, knn, embedding, opensearch

We have a cluster running with a single index with embeddings indexed. We are performing knn search on this cluster.

```
Cluster document size = 54M records
Shards = 10 
Embeddings size = 64 dimension
```

I have tried both a-knn (approximate knn) and script_score knn_score by applying pre-filter.

1. In case of a-knn, it takes too much time and doesn't respond at all (on kibana). On aws dashboard, latencies are > 60 seconds (yes, seconds)
2. In case script score knn, I have applied a filter to give documents within 2km radius (around 50k documents), then it gives results within 400ms. If I just increase the increase the pre-filter radius to 2.5km (around 100k) records, latencies shoot up again.

Here are the settings/mappings and kibana query

```
   {
        "search_item_embedding_v2": {
            "aliases": {
                "search_item_embedding": {}
            },
            "mappings": {
                "properties": {
                    "cityId": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "embeddingsV1": {
                        "type": "knn_vector",
                        "dimension": 64
                    },
                    "embeddingsV2": {
                        "type": "knn_vector",
                        "dimension": 64
                    },
                    "enabled": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "isLongDistanceEnabled": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "isRestEnabled": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "latLong": {
                        "type": "geo_point"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "restId": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "restName": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "vegIdentifier": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "version": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            },
            "settings": {
                "index": {
                    "search": {
                        "slowlog": {
                            "level": "info",
                            "threshold": {
                                "fetch": {
                                    "warn": "90ms",
                                    "debug": "30ms",
                                    "info": "40ms"
                                },
                                "query": {
                                    "warn": "90ms",
                                    "debug": "30ms",
                                    "info": "40ms"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "refresh_interval": "60s",
                    "indexing": {
                        "slowlog": {
                            "level": "info",
                            "threshold": {
                                "index": {
                                    "warn": "500ms",
                                    "debug": "100ms",
                                    "info": "300ms"
                                }
                            },
                            "source": "1000"
                        }
                    },
                    "number_of_shards": "10",
                    "auto_expand_replicas": "0-all",
                    "blocks": {
                        "read_only_allow_delete": "false",
                        "write": "false"
                    },
                    "provided_name": "search_item_embedding_v2",
                    "knn": "true",
                    "creation_date": "1638438116281",
                    "number_of_replicas": "1",
                    "uuid": "-tzXpNRfTY-hTBvu_NKPIA",
                    "version": {
                        "created": "135217827"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Kibana query (method 2):

```
{
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "isRestEnabled": {
                  "value": true,
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "enabled": {
                  "value": true,
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "geo_distance": {
                "latLong": [
                  77.693052,
                  12.928925
                ],
                "distance": "2km",
                "distance_type": "arc",
                "validation_method": "STRICT",
                "ignore_unmapped": false,
                "boost": 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "script": {
        "source": "knn_score",
        "lang": "knn",
        "params": {
          "field": "embeddingsV1",
          "query_value": [],
          "space_type": "cosinesimil"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "id",
      "restId"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried different [encoders](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/search-plugins/knn/knn-index#knn_vector-data-type) and encoder parameters? 54M is a decent dataset so you'll have to fine-tune the parameters.

Comment: will try that and see. thanks.

Comment: even with encoders, do you think a-knn will work (where we can't add pre-filter) within 500ms ? @ilvar

Comment: We were running IVF (with FAISS though, not ES) on a 7M document set (I don't remember dimensionality though.. 300?) with decent performance though 54M is an order of magnitude larger. You can also try using [PQ](https://www.pinecone.io/learn/product-quantization/) to reduce memory usage and speed up the search.

Comment: If you’re open to using a managed service for this, look at [Pinecone](https://www.pinecone.io) - ANN through 54M vectors should be less than a second.